# Nanomsg import error

Tags: python, connection, nanomsg

I'm having problems using NanoMsg. I was using default sockets before but then someone pointed out that this was a bad idea. So I searched to get a better package and found NanoMsg. When I tried importing I got this error:

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
================= RESTART: C:\Users\user\Desktop\Website.py =================

=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
>>> import nanomsg

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\user\lib\site-packages\nanomsg_wrappers\__init__.py", line 22
    "%s, performance may be affected!") % (default,))
UserWarning: Could not load the default wrapper for your platform: cpy, performance may be affected!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import nanomsg
  File "C:\Users\user\lib\site-packages\nanomsg\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import wrapper
  File "C:\Users\user\lib\site-packages\nanomsg\wrapper.py", line 4, in <module>
    _wrapper = _load_wrapper()
  File "C:\Users\user\lib\site-packages\nanomsg_wrappers\__init__.py", line 23, in load_wrapper
    return importlib.import_module('_nanomsg_ctypes')
  File "C:\Users\user\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\user\lib\site-packages\_nanomsg_ctypes\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    _lib = ctypes.windll.nanomsg
  File "C:\Users\user\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 417, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\user\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
>>>
```

Any solutions?